# Return Oracle LONG value from SSIS Execute SQL Task

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ssis, ssis-2012

I have a procedure in Oracle that takes a varchar2 as input and returns a long.

I want to run that procedure from SSIS, and then use that value in subsequent SSIS steps.

I have a sequence container, so once I have received that result, I can use it.  But I am failing at calling the procedure.  I try various things, and always get an error.

Here is what I have:

In Oracle, my procedure (and it's not mine, so I can't change it) is defined as

```
P_CREATE_BATCH (V_NAME IN VARCHAR2, V_BATCH OUT LONG)
```

In SSIS, I have a Variable called v_batch which is Int32 and has a value of 0.
I also have an Execute SQL Task.  It has an OLE connection to the Oracle database.  The SourceType is Direct input, the ResultSet is Single row, and my SQL Query is

```
BEGIN
  P_CREATE_BATCH ('FACT_METER',?);
END;
```

I have Parameter Mapping from user::v_batch, direction Output, Data Type LONG, Parameter 0.
I have a Result Name called MyBatch, with a Variable Name of User::v_batch.

And when I run it, I get the error:

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "BEGIN P_CREATE_BATCH
>   ('FACT_METER',?); END;" failed with the following error: "ORA-06550:
>   line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in
>   call to 'P_CREATE_BATCH' ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL:
>   Statement ignored". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query,
>   "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly,
>   or connection not established correctly.

I have tried it with my variable having at data type of Int64.  I have tried with Result Set of none.  I have forgotten how many different permutations I've tried.  Sometimes I get a different error, but it's because I'm trying something that is obviously wrong.

How do I successfully call an Oracle procedure that returns a LONG, and get that value in SSIS?

**Update, based on comment:** 
The underlying table that is written to (in Oracle) has a data type of number(18).  I have made a version of the Oracle procedure that returns NUMBER, instead of LONG.

When I call it, it still gives me an error, and I think it's because I need a different type for my SSIS variable.  The procedure does run, and then returns the error

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "BEGIN
>   P_CREATE_BATCHK ('FACT_METER',?);
>   END;" failed with the following error: "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
>   ORA-06512: at line 1". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

I have my parameter as Data Type NUMERIC and my variable as Int32, and then Int64, then Double, then UInt64, then Decimal.  There aren't a lot of options left.

**Update**
If I have my SSIS variable as Double, and my parameter data type as Double, with no result set, the task runs.  I don't know yet if I can access the return value, but there isn't an error, so it's progress.

Comment: Are you aware that in Oracle a `LONG` is *not* a numeric type, but rather an obsolete type of LOB?

Comment: @BobJarvis  I was not.  And that might be a vital clue to help us resolve this.

Comment: @BobJarvis - even though that's a short note, we did a lot of searching, so I think the question could still be valid.  If you were to convert you comment to an answer, and suggest using NUMBER on the Oracle side, DOUBLE on the SSIS side, I would accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LONG` is not a numeric type in Oracle - it's a deprecated variety of LOB. In Oracle you should use the type NUMBER to store numeric values. NUMBER is the basic data type used to store a base-10 floating point value with 38 digits of precision, and thus does not suffer from the problem of having values (such as 0.1) which cannot be represented in e.g. IEEE-754 binary floating point values. On the SSIS side this would correspond to, variously, DOUBLE, INT, DECIMAL, etc - i.e. all the numeric types.